# Swiper 5 with lazysizes

Tags: lazy-loading, swiper.js

I need help with lazy load. I am using this swiper here (https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper)to create a full screen swiper on a website which is set on autoplay and has a fade in effect. To reduce the loading time I also included lazysizes (https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) because with the lazy load within the swiper my captions didn't work. They were always overlapping.

However my issue now is that somehow it loads images even then they are not in the viewpoint. I am pretty new to coding, so please bare with me :) I post my code below and hope that someone can help me out here or explain what I need to do. Thanks so much!

```
  <div class="swiper-container">
      
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">

        <picture alt="" class="swiper-slide">
                  <source  class="lazyload" media="(max-width:600px)"
                   data-srcset="images/Loremipsum_mobile.jpg"
                  />
                  <source class="lazyload"
                    media="(max-width: 1024px)"
                    data-srcset="images/Loremipsum.jpg"
                  />
                  <img
                    class="lazyload" 
                    data-src="images/Loremipsum.jpg" 
                  />
                  <div class="image_caption">Titel: Lorem Ipsum</div> 
        </picture>

           
    </div>
        

    <!-- Add Arrows -->
    <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>
      
    <div class="navbar">
       <a href="4s_impressum.html" id="desktop" >Impressum & Datenschutzerklärung</a>
       <a href="4s_impressum.html" id="mobile">i</a>
    </div>
      
  </div>



<!-- Swiper JS -->
    <script src="js/swiper.js"></script>
<!-- Lazysizes -->
    <script src="js/lazysizes.min.js" async=""></script>

<!-- Initialize Swiper -->
  <script>
      
      
      
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        
        // Disable preloading of all images
        preloadImages: false,
        
        // Enable lazy loading
        lazyload: true,
        loop: true,
        effect: 'fade',
//      speed: 0,
        
        keyboard: {
        enabled: true,
//        onlyInViewport: false,
        },
        
                     
        navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
        
        autoplay: {
        delay: 3000,
        //disableOnInteraction: true,
        loop: true, 
        },
        
        
        
    });
      
      
  </script>
```